# change button appearance on click

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, button, click, appearance

I wahnt to change button appearance when it was clicked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Button xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
          creationComplete="init()">        
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public var _clicked:Boolean = false;

            public function init():void{
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeButtonClickStatus);            
            }

            public function changeButtonClickStatus(event:MouseEvent):void{
                var that:TopMenuButton = event.currentTarget as TopMenuButton;
                that._clicked = !(that._clicked);

                if(that._clicked == true){
                //change button appearance
                }else{
                //change button appearance
                }
            }   
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Button>
```

Is there a method using states? I could then use the skin convention.
Thanks in advance for Your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a ToggleButton that you can skin the different states of then [it already exists](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex/web/#docIndex=0;illustIndex=0;sampleId=30500) in Flex 4.

Check out the source code for ToggleButtonSkin.mxml to see how to skin the different states.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the following example:

[Applying styles to different states on a Spark Button control in Flex 4](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/08/10/applying-styles-to-different-states-on-a-spark-button-control-in-flex-4/)